# Not able to add zxing library in my current project

Tags: android-studio

So ,I have downloaded the Zxing file and also extracted it ,but after this I dont have any idea what I have to do to bring this file to my current project,Can somebody help Me to sort this ,problem. I have applied all the processes mention on google  but still when I m writing code & importing the zxing file .It is showing too many error as "Can't resolve symbol zxing".. And so on .please tell me what I have to do after downloading & extracting Zxing-master (in simple steps plz)

After downloading & extracting it ,I create a new project,then add the zxing-master in app directory and then clicked on project structures->module->app->add dependency. After this I added dependency in gradle also ,.But still while i m writing the code for scanning in main activity it is showing too many errors "can't resolve symbol zxing ".. And so on